# Delete session after close window

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I override the OnBeforeUnload dialog and replace it with my own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own)
>   [destroy session on window close?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959655/destroy-session-on-window-close)
>   [How to execute ajax function onbeforeunload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701734/how-to-execute-ajax-function-onbeforeunload)

i want to delete the session after user close window . i don't know how to do this . please help me . i tried following code its working fine IE browser but not working in other browsers . is there any other way to solve this problem

```
$(window).unload( function (event) 
{ 
     if (window.event.clientX < 0 && window.event.clientY < 0)
     {
     alert("closeddddddddddd");
     $.ajax({ url: "logout.php"});
     }
 } );
```

Comment: I think if you close your browser, the session will automatically cleared, am I right?

Comment: but in a limited time i want to get immediate logged out because iam making a chat application and in this if user is closing that window than it should be reflect in my database