# Clear PHP session on browser close

Tags: php

Hey guys can anyone get me out from a problem. I am just checking browser close event, destroy php session if user closed the browser or closed all tabs of the same site.

I used some scripts but they are destroying session on page refresh(F5 or CTRL+R or browser refresh button).

I only need to check browser close button or ALT+F4..

In short call a php function using AJAX when user completely close the browser or close all the tabs.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: It is not possible to detect a browser close event from within a web site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [destroy session on window close?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959655/destroy-session-on-window-close)

Answer (score 4):

Sessions should be automatically discarded as soon as the user closes his/her browser. UNLESS, there is some sort of "Remember Me" function in place.

Comment: thank for the comment, i used Remember Me functionality, i need to check browser close forcefully.

Comment: If you're using Remember Me functionality, why are you trying to kill their login after they've closed their browser? Doesn't that make the Remember Me functionality useless?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to guarantee your server can be aware the user has closed their browser - don't attempt to achieve this.

The session will be automatically lost when the user closes their browser because the browser will not retain the cookie used to associate itself with the generated PHP session. But again that's not something necessarily guaranteed. You probably need to be asking a different question.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment

Answer (score 1):

PHP Session work's that way :

It stores a Static Variable Type of Array for every instance ,and it identifies the Session Variable by storing a Hash Value as a Cookie Called **PHPSESSID** .

That Cookie life time is while Browser is open ,on Browser close that Cookie get discarded.

Some browser could store that Cookie Forever ,but Session has a Timeout on the Server Side.

The case you could run a function on Browser Close is impossible ,because Browser Kill's all Running JavaScript's on Exit.

Comment: The _default_ lifetime of the session cookie is 0, i.e. marked as "delete when client session is closed". But that _can_ be changed, see http://docs.php.net/session.configuration#ini.session.cookie-lifetime. And ... there are other ways to transfer the session id, yet they have other (and bigger) problems.

Answer (score 0):

The session is automatically destroyed when the browser is closed, what are you trying to do ?

Comment: thank for the comment, but i need to check browser close forcefully.

Comment: This does not seem to be a good solution, can you please be more specific and tell us what you want to do ?