# How to store log time when the user closed the browser

Tags: php, session, cookies, phpmyadmin

i created a small application.in that application i want to store the log-in and log-out time.The user logged-in correctly but at the time of log-out the user directly closes the browser.how to store log-out time..

in my application i created a button log-out if the user click on the log-out button there is no problem.but the user closes the browser directly with out click on the log-out button.in this situation how to store the log-out time of a user.

plz help me..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clear PHP session on browser close](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107395/clear-php-session-on-browser-close)

Comment: You can try to use the [`window.onunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onunload)

Comment: Not exactly @Quentin, he's asking about sorting it, not exporting the session.

Answer (score 2):

If I am right, you cannot run any script when a user closes browser.

You could store the time into session: like

```
$_SESSION['LAST_REQUEST_TIME'] = time() ;
```

Each time the user updates a page on your website a new time is set.

Also, save the time into database, because session is destroyed once a user closes browser.

Comment: if he didn't work for some time  then he close the browser directly.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: There is no reliable way to detect the user closing the browser (short of some allways-running ajax heartbeat). JavaScript is only a bit of help, as it won't catch browser crash, loss of network connectivity, etc.

That said, what you might really want is the timestamp of the last request in a login session - and this is trivial to get. You just update a `last_seen` timestamp on every request with a fitting session ID.

Answer (score 0):

You should store last request time to db and compare with the new request time and if it's greater than decided time (e.g. 15 min) you can ask for login.